# Sinned when born?

Tags: sin, original-sin

I am somewhat confused. We are born sinners already?
We didn't do anything bad or harmed anyone and are just born, and right away we are sinners?

Not trying to sound stupid or anything, and am myself a believer, but this just makes very little sense to me, and seems to be quite unfair. Yes it says that we are conceived through sin and yada yada yada, but how is that our fault? Why even be born or come to earth if we are sinners? Logically makes very little sense that God would put us on earth and make us sinners right away. What if I never wanted to be one?

Comment: Also closely related [How is it that someone who lived thousands of years ago can "represent" me?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/3834)

Comment: This is a reasonable question and certainly something everybody should wrestle with and figure out the answer too. There are some circles in Christianity that reject the idea of original sin, while others that embrace it as best explaining Scripture and the state of affairs we see.

Comment: Why don't you review the questions I have linked and perhaps some others in the [tag:original-sin] tag to get an general idea of what what the term "original-sin" means in the context of Christianity. Then if you have something specific that isn't making sense about it, come back here and ask that specific question and we'll see if we can help you further.

Comment: I'm sure those won't cover all the bases and might not fully answer your question about what the doctrine really means, but since this was a really general question I figured it would be better to cover the stuff that has been covered first then we can help you with more specific questions next. Good luck with the reading/research.

Comment: @Caleb I read the duplicate and it doesn't answer my question. Adam and Eve didn't know the rules. If I wasn't taught to not have temptations then yes I would eat the apple. However I do know that I should get rid of all my temptations. You can counter that by saying that newborns do not know the rules when they are born. But at the same time newborns do not have temptations and are born pure, it is the evil in the world that starts giving us temptations. So why would we be sinners from the get go?

Comment: Ok Just FYI, comments aren't the place to discuss the actually nuts and bolts of theological issues so I'm going to skip that for now. Let's work on your question situation. It sounds like the first bit you should ask a question about is something along the lines of "According to Christianity, Did Adam and Eve know the rules?" Why don't you start with that then we'll try to figure out what to ask next. There are several assumptions buried in your statements that need to be rooted out if you're going to understand the teaching.

Comment: I agree those aren't duplicates and the question is specific enough. He's asking "Why are we born as sinners?". I would just like to see where Quillion got this information, and from what doctrine, and from what doctrinal (if anything specific) answers he is looking for. Maybe he can post some references.

Comment: @Shredder There is a difference between being born a sinner (we're not; no-one sins individually in the womb) and being born with Original Sin (which we are).

Comment: @AndrewLeach Yes, and the OP seems to be under the impression of the prior.